# Access function or expression equivalent of SQL ROW_NUMBER()?

Tags: t-sql, ms-access

Is there anything I can do in Access that would mimic the behavior of the TSQL ROW_NUMBER() function, when doing an INSERT query?

Comment: You want it during an INSERT?

Comment: Yessir. I see the answers so far involve writing a subquery that selects count().. Not sure if this works within an INSERT since it would be selecting from the destination table - does Access do INSERTs sequentially (1 row at a time)?

Answer (score 5):

An oldie but goodie:

**How to Rank Records Within a Query**
https://web.archive.org/web/20150310153206/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208946

Answer (score 0):

An Other option would be to use a small piece of VBA (that is if you are really working in Access, not just using an Access database)

```
Option Compare Database
Dim rn As Long

Function ResetRownumber() As String
    rn = 0
    ResetRownumber = "OK"
End Function
Function RowNumber(dummyID As Integer) As Long
    If (dummyID > 0) Then
        rn = rn + 1
        RowNumber = rn
    End If
End Function
```

You call ResetRownumber() before you start your Query
And then

```
SELECT RowNumber(anyfield) AS RowNum, OtherField FROM SomeTable
```

This will give you a rownumber.
Passing one of the selected fieldnames is not optional, otherwise the VBA function is only called once and not for every row.
**Warning:** Use it only on a limited number of records as your query will be slowing down significantly by calling the VBA code for every selected row.