# Update Table to order child records by date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables:

PARENT (EMAIL,NAME,ETC)
CHILD (EMAIL,DOC_DOC_ID,DOWNLOAD_DATE,RANK)

I need to generate a query that will update the CHILD.RANK Field, with a numerical sorting that will rank each distinct DOC_ID by the date that it was downloaded (1 = latest doc download)

```
SELECT
    P.EMAIL,
    C.DOC_ID,
    MAX(C.DOWNLOAD_DATE)
FROM
    PARENT P,
    CHILD C
WHERE
    P.EMAIL = C.EMAIL
```

Please dont laugh at what i have come up with so far!... i think my brain is fried!

Comment: Can you elaborate? You want to update CHILD.RANK with a number? Why do you need the PARENT table?

Comment: SQL Server has the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to create the rank value. However, MS Access dose not support it. Check out this question for doing it in MS Access - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516739/access-function-or-expression-equivalent-of-sql-row-number

Comment: The Child Rank is grouped by the email id.. so yes, technically you dont need the parent table...IF Several different docs are downloaded on the same day, they you will take the latest record for that particular email... grouped by the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rank_ID for more than display (which should be left to the queries) your design may have issues.

Have you considered what would happen if you checked out DOC_ID = 1 today and then ran an update to give it rank one and then the same thing happened tomorrow and you now have two records for DOC_ID = 1 with a RANK of 1?

You could use something like this to just display the records in the correct order.  **Query 1** will just display the records in order. **Query 2** will add a Rank value (requires the first query).

```
QUERY 1:
SELECT
    LAST(EMAIL) AS EMAIL,
    DOC_DOC_ID,
    Max(DOWNLOAD_DATE) AS DOWNLOAD_DATE
FROM 
    CHILD
GROUP BY 
    DOC_DOC_ID
ORDER BY 
    Max(DOWNLOAD_DATE) DESC;


QUERY 2:
SELECT 
    testing.EMAIL, 
    testing.DOC_DOC_ID, 
    testing.DOWNLOAD_DATE, 
    (select 
         count(*)
     from
         Query1
     where
         DOWNLOAD_DATE>testing.DOWNLOAD_DATE)+1 AS RANK
FROM
    Query1 as testing
ORDER BY
    testing.DOWNLOAD_DATE DESC;
```

Comment: yes... thanks for this... the query is actually for a once of data cleanup. so i imagine the data will be static for now... Good advice though. i will check out the solution. Thanks