# How to show the record number in a MS Access report table?

Tags: ms-access, report

I'm using MS Access to make a small piece of software for an office. When we insert a record the record ID does not always follow the sequence of natural numbers, starting from 1. but in the first column I want a self-generated serial number(S.N).

```
SN  |   Discription |
----+---------------+
1   |   Computer    |
2   |   Mobile      |
```

I Want these S.N to always start from 1 and count all records in the report table Plsease help.

Comment: What do you mean by "and count all records in report table "?

Comment: then count each records line by line and add in 1 so that the result in the cloumn will be 1,2,3,4,5,..

Comment: My understanding is that you want these serial numbers only on the report. If the first record "Computer" is deleted from the database, "Mobile" will then show up with S.N. 1?

Comment: Yes @Tarik you are right. Please if you have suggest an idea.

Comment: The following similar questions has been asked and are still unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872305/ms-access-alternative-to-sql-function-row-number and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877224/access-query-producing-results-like-row-number-in-t-sql

Answer (score 1):

I assume your table name is inventory:

```
SELECT DCOUNT("[Description]","[inventory]","[Description]<='" & [Description] & "'") AS rank, inventory.*
FROM inventory
ORDER BY [Description]
```

DCOUNT function counts the number of rows that satisfy the a given criteria. In this case we count the number of rows that are less than the current row. Things will work if the column you use has unique values.