# Retrieve last N records from a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2013

I have searched but not found an answer for my question.

I have a table orders that consists of

- id (primary key autonumber)
- client_id : identifies each client (unique)
- date: order dates for each client

I want to retrieve the last N order dates for each client in a single view

Of course I could use `SELECT TOP N date FROM orders WHERE client = 'xx' ORDER DESC` and then use `UNION` for the different values for client.  The problem is that with changes in client base the statement would require revision and that the `UNION` statement is impractical with a large client base.

As an additional requirement this needs to work in Access SQL.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Create a query that yields a *rank order by date per client* for every row. Since Access SQL does not have `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...)` like SQL Server, you can simulate this by using the technique described in the following question:

- [Access query producing results like ROW_NUMBER() in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877224/access-query-producing-results-like-row-number-in-t-sql)

If you have done step 1 correctly, your result should be as follows:

```
id   client_id    date      rank
----------------------------------
        1       2014-12-01   7 
        1       2014-12-02   6 
        1       2014-12-05   5 
        1       2014-12-07   4 
        1       2014-12-11   3 
        1       2014-12-14   2 
        1       2014-12-15   1 
        2       2014-12-01   2 
        2       2014-12-02   1
       ...
```

**Step 2**: Use the result from step 1 as a subquery and filter the result such that only records with `rank <= N` are returned.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will work in MS Access:

```
select t.*
from table as t
where t.date in (select top N t2.date
                 from table as t2
                 where t2.client_id = t.client_id
                 order by t2.date desc
                );
```

One problem with MS Access is that `top N` will retrieve more than `N` records if there are ties.  If you want exactly "N", then you can use `order by date, id` in the subquery.

Comment: Good idea, but I think you need to do the WHERE comparison on `id`, not on `date`. Consider the case where three customers order on `2014-12-01`, but it is only "relevant" (i.e., within the last five orders) for two of them. Your query would return all three records.

Comment: @Heinzi . . . I don't understand your comment.  I think the OP is pretty clear "last N order dates for each client".  Of course, if the OP means `id` and not `date` in the definition of "last N order dates" then s/he can of course use that field.  As for the number of customers, that is handled by the interaction of `top` with `order by`.

Comment: Ah, I understand. You are right, of course: I thought he wants "the last N order dates *for each client*", i.e., a table `client_id, date` with at most N entries for each client_id. Of course, the UNION example he gives would result in "all dates which are within the last 5 order dates for *any* client". Your SQL perfectly solves this problem. I still believe that he might in fact want the first interpretation (which would make more sense).

Comment: Thank you Gordon that does exactly what I needed. Many thanks you made my day,