# SQL - Count(*) not behaving in expected manner

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have the following code

```
SELECT C_Record.BunchOfColumns, Count(*) AS Degrees 
FROM C_Record
WHERE (((C_Record.[C#])=[Enter Value])) //Parameter Input from User
GROUP BY C_Record.BunchofColumns;
```

My Degrees column never increments, it shows 1 always no matter how many rows are returned from the query. I am suspecting that I have not implemented my `GROUP BY` method properly. If I understand it correctly, all columns that are selected and are not part of the aggregate function (`COUNT` in my case) should be put together in `GROUP BY`. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

**Edit**: What I am trying to achieve is to check how many rows have a particular value for a column, then select all other relevant columns and create a Index columns. For example if there are three rows that meet my requirement

```
Col1 Col2 Degrees
 A     X    1
 B     Y    2
 C     Z    3
```

and if only 2 rows meet my requirement then

```
Col1 Col2 Degrees
 P     X    1
 Q     Y    2
```

P.S - my C_Record.BunchofColumns consists of about 10 columns that I did not include for the sake of brevity.

P.P.S - If I try to skip out on any column it gives me the error `You Tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression <<column_name>> as part of an aggregate function`

Comment: Is the `Degrees` column just 1, 2, 3, 4, etc., or is there some other logic I'm missing?

Comment: If that is the case, then [you forgot the JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21878831/1340389).

Comment: I see. I think that is exactly what I need. Thanks Kevin. If you can update your answer...I'll mark it as complete

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Count()` with a `GROUP BY` the count returned is the number of rows in each group.  So to get a count greater than one you would have to have more than one row in your table that had exactly the same values.  If you are selecting 10 different columns it seems likely that you have no two columns in the database that have exactly those 10 same values.

If you start with a selecting and grouping by a single column you will see count's of more than one.

Comment: That is what I had done initially...But if I don't include the other columns, I get the error message. Maybe there is a different way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how GROUP BY works.

GROUP BY completely changes the meaning of your query.  Each row of the result is an "aggregate grouping" of the original rows.  Each aggregate grouping consists of all the rows with a particular combination of values for their GROUP BY columns.  So if you GROUP BY ten columns, each grouping will consist of rows which are identical on all ten columns.

Once these groupings have been formed, you SELECT various aggregate values like `count()` or `sum()`, which provide you with information about the group as a whole.  `count(*)` gives you the number of rows in the group, while `count(column)` gives you the number of rows in which `column` is non-NULL.  You can also select any of the columns which appear in the GROUP BY clause, because those columns are identical across the whole group.

You are getting a `count(*)` of one because each of your groups only contains a single row.  This is probably because you are grouping by ten columns, and there are no two rows which are identical for all ten columns.

If you just want a count of how many rows satisfy some query, and you don't want this aggregation at all, you write it like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM something
WHERE something
-- no GROUP BY
;
```

That will form a *single* aggregate group of your whole query, and count the rows.

If you want something else, you will need to further explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say..that is what I had done initially. But If i dont include all the columns I get the error message. at this point I am looking for a different method of doing this. I just can't limit it to count(*)...I need to select other columns too. Otherwise my report will make no sense

Comment: What do you actually want the results to look like?  I mean, do you want to have the same count value in every row?  I just don't see the point of that.

Comment: @kevin..updated the question