# MS Access SQL pagination with a query (no unique identifier) or ROW_NUMBER?

Tags: sql, ms-access, pagination, self-join

I am trying to grab 100 rows at a time from a SQL query and use them for pagination. The query returns ~2000 rows from a table with 100,000+ rows. However, the table does not have a unique identifier.

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM tbl_Items WHERE tbl_Items.Repair_Required = true
```

I have looked into using ROW_NUMBER but it seems like that's not available in MS Access. I have also looked into creating a custom row_number using "self-join" as answered by Gord Thompson here: [Access query producing results like ROW_NUMBER() in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877224/access-query-producing-results-like-row-number-in-t-sql). However, joining my 100,000+ table with itself would be not be easy on performance.

What are my options?

Comment: Joining 100k records with itself should be easy.

Comment: @GordThompson - I have removed my comment with my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using a collection and it works really fast:

```
Public Function RowCounter( _
  ByVal strKey As String, _
  ByVal booReset As Boolean, _
  Optional ByVal strGroupKey As String) _
  As Long

' Builds consecutive RowIDs in select, append or create query
' with the possibility of automatic reset.
' Optionally a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowCounter(vbNullString, False)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter("",True)=0);
'
' 2002-04-13. Cactus Data ApS. CPH
' 2002-09-09. Str() sometimes fails. Replaced with CStr().
' 2005-10-21. Str(col.Count + 1) reduced to col.Count + 1.
' 2008-02-27. Optional group parameter added.

  Static col      As New Collection
  Static strGroup As String

  On Error GoTo Err_RowCounter

  If booReset = True Or strGroup <> strGroupKey Then
    Set col = Nothing
    strGroup = strGroupKey
  Else
    col.Add col.Count + 1, strKey
  End If

  RowCounter = col(strKey)

Exit_RowCounter:
  Exit Function

Err_RowCounter:
  Select Case Err
    Case 457
      ' Key is present.
      Resume Next
    Case Else
      ' Some other error.
      Resume Exit_RowCounter
  End Select
End Function
```

Please study the in-line comments and examples.

Of course, you would apply it to the query with the 2000 records, not the source table(s).