# How to make a query where a one to many table's result is put into columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables company and phone. The phone number table has a one to many relation with company where one company can have many phone numbers. How can I make a query that will take each phone number corresponding to a company and put them all on one row along with the company?

Table Structures and Data examples:

```
Table one: Company Table
Fields: CompanyID, CompanyName
                1, ABC
                2, DEF
                3, GHI

Table Two: Phone Number
Fields: Id, CompanyID, Phone
         1,         1, 555-5551
         2,         1, 555-5552
         3,         2, 555-5553
         4,         3, 555-5554
```

I want to make a query that would result in

```
Company Name,   Phone1,   Phone2
         ABC, 555-5551, 555-5552
         DEF, 555-5553
         GHI, 555-5554
```

Is there a way to make a query that would make this pivot.

In the past I managed to do this by giving the phone table an additional field called type so that the user had to specify if it was a Cell phone, land line, mobile and then the query would just have select statements within the select statement to look for that specific type, but I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid having to add an additional field to the phone numbers table. And if there is such a way to do this, what the terminology for this is as well.

Comment: What you want is a crosstab query - it will take multiple related rows and place into one row. And just be be a stickler, your statement "The phone number table has a one to many relation with company... " you should flip the table names. Yes there is a 'one to many', but one Company to many phones.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, @cha's approach is close, except you won't get the column headings you want. In order to have it count off the number of unique phone numbers, you need to do some trickery with self-join queries (because Access/Jet doesn't have ROW_NUMBER() or RANK() like other SQL flavors) as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21878831/6591527). Making a query to do this, and then a crosstab off of that, will affect performance. If you only have hundreds of records, you probably won't notice it, but if it's thousands, you might. This is why you're better off having a column identifying what each phone number corresponds to. (And, in terms of accessing that data as an end user, wouldn't you want to know whether you're calling someone's office or home phone anyway?).

So, if you do want to proceed with this route, here is what you do. First, you have a query to label each phone number:

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.CompanyID, p1.Phone, "Phone" & count(*) As PhoneRank
FROM [Phone Number] as p1 INNER JOIN [Phone Number] AS p2 
ON (p1.CompanyID = p2.CompanyID) AND (p1.ID >= p2.ID)
GROUP BY p1.ID, p1.CompanyID, p1.Phone;
```

The results look like this:
[image]

Then, as @cha said, do a cross tab query, and join to the Company table in the process. I prefer to avoid the query wizards. My crosstab design view looks like this:

[image]

And the final result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I was about to edit my answer. You are first, so I am deleting mine